# How to evaluate $\int \frac{\mathrm{dx}}{x^4[x(x^5-1)]^{1/3}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

How to evaluate: $$\int \frac{\mathrm{dx}}{x^4[x(x^5-1)]^{1/3}}$$
I have done a substantial work on it:

---

Let $x^5z^3=x^5-1$. So
$$x^5(z^3-1)=1\implies 5x^4(z^3-1)\mathrm{d}x+x^5(-3z^2\mathrm{d}z)=0\implies \mathrm{d}x=\frac{3xz^2\mathrm{d}z}{5(z^3-1)}$$
So:
$$\int \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^4[x(x^5-1)]^{1/3}}\text{ or }\int x^{-13/3}(x^5-1)^{-1/3}\mathrm{d}x\\
=\int x^{-13/3}(x^5z^3)^{-1/3}.\frac{3xz^2\mathrm{d}z}{5(z^3-1)}=\frac35\int \frac{x^{-13/3}x^{-5/3}z^{-1}xz^2\mathrm{d}z}{x^{-5}}\\
=\frac35\int z\;\mathrm{d}z=\frac{3}{10}\left(\frac{x^5-1}{x^5}\right)^{2/3}+\mathcal{C}$$
Is my working correct? Is there an easier way?

---

Actually(thanks to **@Jean-ClaudeArbaut**):

- $x^5(\color{red}{1-z^3})=1$
- $5x^4(z^3-1)\mathrm{d}x+x^5(\color{red}{3}z^2\mathrm{d}z)=0$

Comment: Just out of curiosity, are all your integrals from a book? (which one?)

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut yes, do you think they're good?

Comment: They are interesting! :-)

Comment: Yeah, I agree, they may be a bit tedious, but they have some level of cleverness involved! Which book is it?

Comment: @Aditya Beware: if $x^5z^3=x^5-1$, then $x^5(z^3-1)=x^5z^3-x^5=-1$, not $1$

Comment: @Aditya: If I were you, I would use the substitution you used.

Comment: @Aditya There is a second sign mistake, when you differentiate (should be $+3z^2\mathrm{d}z$). Thus $\mathrm{d}x$ changes sign, but the sign is annihilated later when you divide by $x^{-5}$, because it should be $-x^{-5}$ (because of the first mistake noticed above). Hence the final result does not change. Apart from that, this is a very clever approach! [As another concern, I would also prove that the change of variable is bijective and differentiable, as it's necessary]

Comment: @Aditya Ohh. I looked over your questions and saw on your bio that you're a high school student and was shocked. Now I'm not, seeing how you plan to apply to IIT. Wow, good luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
\int \dfrac{1}{x^4\left[x\left(x^5-1\right)\right]^{1/3}}dx\tag{1}
$$

use the sub $u = 1/x^3\implies du = -\dfrac{3}{x^4} dx$.

thus Eq. (1) becomes

$$
\int \dfrac{1}{\left(\dfrac{1}{u^2}-\dfrac{1}{u^{1/3}}\right)^{1/3}}\dfrac{du}{-3} = \dfrac{1}{-3}\int \dfrac{u^{2/3}}{\left(1-u^{5/3}\right)^{1/3}}du
$$

then $v = \left(1-u^{5/3}\right)^{2/3}$

$$
dv = \dfrac{2}{3}\dfrac{-\dfrac{5}{3}u^{2/3}}{\left(1-u^{5/3}\right)^{1/3}}\rightarrow -\dfrac{9}{10}dv = \dfrac{u^{2/3}}{\left(1-u^{5/3}\right)^{1/3}}du
$$

I think this correct, but then again I have made mistakes in the past!