# Integration by nonobvious substitutions

Tags: integration, big-list

The standard technique for evaluating the integral
$$\int \sec x \,dx$$
is making the nonobvious substitution
$$u = \sec x + \tan x, \qquad du = (\sec x \tan x + \sec^2 x) dx,$$ which transforms the integral to
$$\int \frac{du}{u} .$$

What are other integrals that are nicely handled with nonobvious substitutions?

Comment: [The world's sneakiest substitution is undoubtedly this technique](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution)

Comment: Note that the tangent half-angle substitution (see above) also works for integrating $\sec x$.

Comment: Like $y=4/x$ in [$K=\int\frac{\ln x\,dx}{x^2+2x+4}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/994426/how-to-integrate-int-frac-ln-x-dxx22x4)

Comment: Or [this one: $\int \frac{\mathrm{dx}}{x^4[x(x^5-1)]^{1/3}}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/906351/how-to-evaluate-int-frac-mathrmdxx4xx5-11-3) with substitution $x^5z^3=x^5-1$

Comment: ADG, perhaps you'd consider writing these up as answers, since they're already complete examples?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're unaware of a substitution, which usually happens when you have'nt attempted a problem of that particular type, the substitution usually seems non-obvious(happened to me a lot when beginning to learn integration), some of the examples which I liked the most are:

> From [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/906351/how-to-evaluate-int-frac-mathrmdxx4xx5-11-3):$$\int \frac{\mathrm{dx}}{x^4[x(x^5-1)]^{1/3}}$$
>
> ---
>
> This one's by me: Let $x^5z^3=x^5-1$. So
>   $$x^5(z^3-1)=1\implies 5x^4(z^3-1)\mathrm{d}x+x^5(-3z^2\mathrm{d}z)=0\implies \mathrm{d}x=\frac{3xz^2\mathrm{d}z}{5(z^3-1)}$$
>   So:
>   $$\int \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^4[x(x^5-1)]^{1/3}}\text{ or }\int x^{-13/3}(x^5-1)^{-1/3}\mathrm{d}x\\
> =\int x^{-13/3}(x^5z^3)^{-1/3}.\frac{3xz^2\mathrm{d}z}{5(z^3-1)}=\frac35\int \frac{x^{-13/3}x^{-5/3}z^{-1}xz^2\mathrm{d}z}{x^{-5}}\\
> =\frac35\int z\;\mathrm{d}z=\frac{3}{10}\left(\frac{x^5-1}{x^5}\right)^{2/3}+\mathcal{C}$$

Another One:

> From [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/994426/how-to-integrate-int-frac-ln-x-dxx22x4) $$K=\int\frac{\ln x\,dx}{x^2+2x+4}$$
>
> ---
>
> Try the substitution $x = \dfrac{4}{y}$ to get:
>
> This one's by **JimmyK4542** $$I = \int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{\ln x}{x^2+2x+4}\,dx = \int_{-\infty}^{0}\dfrac{\ln \frac{4}{y}}{\frac{16}{y^2}+\frac{8}{y}+4} \cdot \dfrac{-4}{y^2}\,dy$$
>
> $$= \int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{\ln 4 - \ln y}{y^2+2y+4}\,dy = \ln 4 \int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{\,dy}{y^2+2y+4} - I$$
>
> Thus, $$2I = \ln 4 \int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{\,dx}{x^2+2x+4}$$, which is easy to compute.